# Jboss Migration from EAP 6.3 to EAP 7.3 - Resource Adapter Not Working

Tags: java, migration, ibm-mq, jboss7.x, message-queue

My application was working without any problem using Java with IBM MQ & wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.7.rar in EAP 6.3 environment. Now due to migration to EAP 7.3, getting the following error while starting the server and tired of finding solution. Kindly assist me to fix this issue.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Global-ear.ear"."Global-ejb.jar".component.ReceivingMsgFromRTL.CREATE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Global-ear.ear"."Global-ejb.jar".component.ReceivingMsgFromRTL.CREATE: Failed to start service
              at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
              at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
              at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
              at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
              at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
              at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEJB0383: No message listener of type javax.jms.MessageListener found in resource adapter wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.7.rar
              at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.createActivationSpecs(MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.java:142)
              at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.createComponent(MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.java:105)
              at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponentCreateService.start(BasicComponentCreateService.java:86)
              at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.start(MessageDrivenComponentCreateService.java:93)
              at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
              at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
              ... 6 more

ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Global-ear.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
    "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Global-ear.ear\".\"Global-ejb.jar\".component.ReceivingMsgFromRTL.CREATE" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEJB0383: No message listener of type javax.jms.MessageListener found in resource adapter wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.7.rar",

INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Global-ear.ear"."Global-ejb.jar".component.ReceivingMsgFromRTL.CREATE: Failed to start service
WFLYCTL0448: 15 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
```

Here are the configuration information I used in **standalone xml**.

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="50000"/>
    <property name="websphere.hostNameEDWReceive" value="WMQ_XXXXXX.yyy.zzz"/>
    <property name="websphere.portEDWReceive" value="12345"/>
    <property name="websphere.channelEDWReceive" value="XXXXXX.CLIENT"/>
    <property name="websphere.transportType" value="CLIENT"/>
    <property name="websphere.queueManagerEDWReceive" value="XXXXXX"/>
    <property name="websphere.resource.adapter" value="wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.7.rar"/>
    <property name="websphere.ReceiveFrmMFeDWRTL" value="VCS.NCI.RTL.ZOS"/>
</system-properties>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:6.0">
    <mdb>
        <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.7.rar"/>
        <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
    </mdb>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
    <resource-adapters>
        <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.7.rar">
            <archive>
                wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.7.rar
            </archive>
            <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
            <config-property name="connectionConcurrency">2</config-property>
            <connection-definitions>
                <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:/jboss/jms/wmq/connectionFactory" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MQConnectionFactory" use-ccm="true">
                    <config-property name="channel">${websphere.channelEDWReceive:XXXXX.CLIENT}</config-property>
                    <config-property name="hostName">${websphere.hostNameEDWReceive:WMQ_XXXXX.yyy.zzz}</config-property>
                    <config-property name="transportType">${websphere.transportType:CLIENT}</config-property>
                    <config-property name="queueManager">${websphere.queueManagerEDWReceive:XXXXX}</config-property>
                    <config-property name="port">${websphere.portEDWReceive:12345}</config-property>
                    <xa-pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                    </xa-pool>
                    <timeout>
                        <allocation-retry>3</allocation-retry>
                        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>5000</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                    </timeout>
                    <recovery no-recovery="true"/>
                </connection-definition>
            </connection-definitions>
            <admin-objects>
                <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:/jboss/jms/wmq/queue/ReceiveFrmMFeDWRTL" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ReceiveFrmMFeDWRTLPool">
                    <config-property name="baseQueueName">${websphere.ReceiveFrmMFeDWRTL:VCS.NCI.RTL.ZOS}</config-property>
                    <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">${websphere.queueManagerEDWReceive:XXXXX}</config-property>
                </admin-object>
            </admin-objects>
        </resource-adapter>
    </resource-adapters>
</subsystem>
```

and **ejb-jar.xml**

```
<message-driven>
  <description>ReceivingMsgFromRTL</description>
  <ejb-name>ReceivingMsgFromRTL</ejb-name>
  <ejb-class>com.nissan.nciservices.global.ejb.ReceivingMsgFromRTL</ejb-class>
  <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
  <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
</message-driven>
```

and **jboss-ejb3.xml**

```
<jee:message-driven>
      <jee:ejb-name>ReceivingMsgFromRTL</jee:ejb-name>
      <jee:ejb-class>com.nissan.nciservices.global.ejb.ReceivingMsgFromRTL</jee:ejb-class>
      <jee:transaction-type>Container</jee:transaction-type>
      <jee:message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</jee:message-destination-type>
      <jee:activation-config>
        <jee:activation-config-property>
          <jee:activation-config-property-name>channel</jee:activation-config-property-name>
          <jee:activation-config-property-value>${websphere.channelEDWReceive}</jee:activation-config-property-value>
        </jee:activation-config-property>
        <jee:activation-config-property>
          <jee:activation-config-property-name>queueManager</jee:activation-config-property-name>
          <jee:activation-config-property-value>${websphere.queueManagerEDWReceive}</jee:activation-config-property-value>
        </jee:activation-config-property>
        <jee:activation-config-property>
          <jee:activation-config-property-name>transportType</jee:activation-config-property-name>
          <jee:activation-config-property-value>${websphere.transportType}</jee:activation-config-property-value>
        </jee:activation-config-property>
        <jee:activation-config-property>
          <jee:activation-config-property-name>hostName</jee:activation-config-property-name>
          <jee:activation-config-property-value>${websphere.hostNameEDWReceive}</jee:activation-config-property-value>
        </jee:activation-config-property>
        <jee:activation-config-property>
          <jee:activation-config-property-name>port</jee:activation-config-property-name>
          <jee:activation-config-property-value>${websphere.portEDWReceive}</jee:activation-config-property-value>
        </jee:activation-config-property>
        <jee:activation-config-property>
          <jee:activation-config-property-name>destination</jee:activation-config-property-name>
          <jee:activation-config-property-value>java:/jboss/jms/wmq/queue/ReceiveFrmMFeDWRTL</jee:activation-config-property-value>
        </jee:activation-config-property>
        <jee:activation-config-property>
          <jee:activation-config-property-name>useJNDI</jee:activation-config-property-name>
          <jee:activation-config-property-value>true</jee:activation-config-property-value>
        </jee:activation-config-property>
        <jee:activation-config-property>
          <jee:activation-config-property-name>destinationType</jee:activation-config-property-name>
          <jee:activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</jee:activation-config-property-value>
        </jee:activation-config-property>
      </jee:activation-config>
    </jee:message-driven>
```

Comment: 7.5 has been out of support for a while now.  I would suggest trying the latest 9.2.0.1 RA.

Comment: Thanks for response Josh. Yes, I have tried wmq.jmsra-9.2.0.0.rar as well, but it does throwed me same error.